# i have to set data into a html file using velocity template?

Tags: java, html, velocity

I have a requirement in which i have to set data in a html file using velocity template. I have to create a table dynamically and also i have to show some static data. I am able to set data dynamically into table but than i am not able to get static data from my list. My problem is that i have to extract both dynamic and static data from single list only.

Velocity code :

```
public static String prepareTemplate(HashMap<String, String> documentContentHashmap,String templateLocation) throws NamingException{
    System.out.println("Document Contents :"+documentContentHashmap);
    ArrayList documentList=new ArrayList();
    documentList.add(documentContentHashmap);
    System.out.println(documentList);
    String templatePath=templateLocation.replaceAll("\\\\","/");
    String[] splittedTemplatePath = templatePath.split("/");
    String templateName=splittedTemplatePath[splittedTemplatePath.length-1];
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("resource.loader","file");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", templatePath.substring(0, templatePath.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/");           
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.cache", "false");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", "0");
    ve.init(properties);
    Template t = ve.getTemplate(templateName);
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    //for (Entry<String, String> entry : documentContentHashmap.entrySet()) {
        //context.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    //}
    context.put("documentList", documentList);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.merge( context, writer );
    System.out.println("writer"+writer);
    String documentBytes=generateDocument(writer);
    if(documentBytes!=null){
        return documentBytes;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Payment Voucher</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <img alt="logo" src="$image_path"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="rightDiv" style="align:right;">
        <label>Invoice Number :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Here i have to access some value from the same documentList  </span><br/>
        <label>Invoice Date :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Here i have to access some value from the same documentList </span>
    </div>
    <table>
    #foreach( $documentContent in $documentList )
        <tr><td>$documentContent.invoice_no</td></tr>
    #end
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an ArrayList use the HashMap directly. Velocity context can take any object type and the functions available on the Map will be available inside the template.

`context.put("documentList", documentList);`

becomes

`context.put("documentList", documentContentHashmap);`

Use it in your template as

```
<div id="rightDiv" style="align:right;">
  <label>Invoice Number :</label><span>access from documentList: $documentList.get("key1")  </span><br/>
  <label>Invoice Date :</label><span>access from documentList: $documentList.get("key2") </span>
</div>
```

Your Iteration code remains same. In case you want to ensure ordering of iteration use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)